# Suddenly xcode hided the views in interface builder Storyboard - iphone

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

The app was working normally, till I committed my code using Git for pushing the code online. The views were hidden from the interface builder (storyboard) suddenly.

It shows the views this way:

[image: Screen shot from Xcode]

the interface builder does not show the faded views as well:

[image: Screen shot from xcode 2]

I tried to check for the source code of the storyboard but nothing looks wrong. what can be a possible error that cause this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at what happens when you have designed your views in a particular size class and then, when you look at the storyboard, you are not in that size class.

For example, let's say you happened to be in size class H:Regular W:Compact when you put "top line" into its superview in Interface Builder. At that time, the bottom of your Interface Builder canvas would have shown something like this:

[image]

That blue is supposed to be a warning that you are working in a specialized size class! But you, I am postulating, paid no attention to that warning.

Okay, so now you come back later and you are in size class H:Any W:Any. What you are showing in your screen shots is just what I would expect to see.

You would also see something like this at the bottom of the attributes inspector when you select one of the views:

[image]

That would show that you've accidentally installed your view in a specialized size class and not in the size class you are in.

Comment: i designed it to work for full ipad size but the design was supposed to work for all sizes as i maintained and tested it on all sizes

Comment: I'm talking about size classes, not sizes.

Comment: Well, you need to switch through the various size classes and figure out whether what I'm saying is true and which size class you've accidentally stuck those views in. Then when you find them you need to delete them and switch back to H:Any WK:Any and put them in there. I may be wrong, but I don't think there's any easy way to move views from one size class to another, sorry.

Comment: You _might_ be able to shorten the process by using the Installed checkboxes at the bottom of the attributes inspector.

Comment: Added a screen shot of the Installed checkboxes.

Comment: I just did, It worked for showing them back, but the whole design is ruined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76743/discussion-between-mbh-and-matt).

Comment: Yep, not much you can do about that. You screwed up when you put the views in the wrong size class. There is no easy solution.

Comment: Added a further screen shot of the "warning" blue thing at the bottom of the window which you would have had to ignore in order to make the mistake I'm suggesting you may have made. :(

Comment: Actually yes i did, I had no idea what this could do. Thanks anyway, you saved me a lot of effort to discover what the heck is this error

Comment: You might be able to save the day by going back and also bringing over the _constraints_. You see, they are also in the wrong size class.